# ApacheSolr Search results with AJAX (D7)

Tags: ajax, javascript, search

I've been searching the web for ways to display my search results directly in a block after submitting the input form with AJAX.

Unfortunatly, i haven't found alot of good information on this subject. Can anyone here point me in the right direction? I'm using Drupal 7.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Solr AJAX](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_ajax) module is available for D6

Project page says

> The Apache Solr AJAX module AJAXifies Apache Solr Search Integration –
>   if you change your query or filters, you see the new result set
>   instantly – no need to reload the full page.

For D7 there exists a [Sandbox Project](https://drupal.org/sandbox/darthsteven/1116776)

You can try the module, Download module using below commands,

```
git clone --branch master http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/darthsteven/1116776.git apache_solr_ajax___d7
cd apache_solr_ajax___d7
```

Found an article here [Drupal7 AJAXified Solr Search with facets. Search API, Panels and some custom code.](http://ygerasimov.com/ajaxified-solr-search-drupal-search-api-views-panels) you can give a try..

Comment: I've been looking at this. Althought they say its a d7 port, it says core = 6.x in the info file. Obviously i can change it, but i dont think its an actual d7 port. For example, it uses "search_get_keys()"  which doesnt exist in D7.

Comment: Updated answer with a link to an article...

Comment: Thanks for the link Anil, but i'd rather not use Panels/Views. I'll keep on looking.